# White spots of mould in the blue mould on the outside of my blue cheese

Tags: cheese

There are white spots of mould in the blue mould on the outside of my blue cheese. Is this normal?

My cheese cave runs at 60F with 85 to 90% humidity. I took this pic today, after the cheese has been in the cave for 20 days:

Contacted Mad Millie and received the following reply:

Are you able to provide a photo of when you cut into the cheese?
It’s looking pretty good!!

The white mould growing is fine, as white mould is not bad for you. It is the dark mould that you need to be more concerned about. Just wipe the mould off with a cloth, do not salt the cheese.

[image: cheese with mold]